# Cancel HyperlinkButton event after it is clicked

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a HyperlinkButton. When I click on it, it launches the internet browser with the link in it as he should do.

I want to cancel this HyperlinkButton event on some conditions.

For example:

- user clicks on the hyperlinkbutton
- app checks the internet connectivity
- if there is no internet connection don't launch the internet browser,
  stay in the app

**Example code (something like that):**

```
<Page x:Class="App1.MainPage" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="using:App1" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid>
    <HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="http://stackoverflow.com/" Content="GO TO WEBPAGE" Click="HyperlinkButton_Click_1" />
</Grid>   
</Page>

private void HyperlinkButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var connectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
    if (connectionProfile == null || connectionProfile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.LocalAccess || connectionProfile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.None) 
    {
         NO INTERNET, CANCEL THE EVENT!!!!!!!!
    }
}
```

So, how can I cancel HyperlinkButton event after it is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `return` keyword.

**MSDN**

```
The return statement terminates execution of the method in which it
appears and returns control to the calling method.
It can also return the value of the optional expression.
If the method is of the type void, the return statement can be omitted.
```

[Further Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a return statement.

```
return;
```

That is,

```
if (condition) 
{
     return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `if` in wrong way. You should do like this.

```
private async void HyperlinkButton_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var connectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
    if (connectionProfile != null && connectionProfile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess)
    {
        //TODO: open link
    }
    else
    {
        await new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Internet is not available.").ShowAsync();
    }
}
```